# Got "Missing separator" error building Cppcheck

Tags: build, makefile, cppcheck

I have trouble building Cppcheck in Windows. It's ok while building in Studio, but when I try build.bat, it fails with the following:

```
Makefile.Release:148: *** missing separator.  Stop.
mingw32-make: *** [release] Error 2
```

I'm not good with all the makefile technology, but the problematic spot does look broken:

```
{..\externals\tinyxml}.cpp{temp\}.obj::
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -Fotemp\ @<<
    $<
<<
```

Looks like something screws the generation of configuration dependent Makefiles. Any ideas?

UPDATE: Could it be related to the fact, I'm building 1.60 using qmake from Qt 5.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this in the root folder should work:

```
mingw32-make LDFLAGS=-lshlwapi
```